# Send Sms using gsm modam using c# and message length is too short

Tags: c#, gsm

I build an SMS app in C# but when I sent a message only 150 char message get sent.
But my client requirement is to send more than 150 char.

How I can do solve?

Comment: Any code to show ?

Comment: @said its limitation of SMS. you can send max 160char in one go. Even please check max char you can send from your mobile device with same SIM so you will have more idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the count of the `string` before sending the message/SMS and then `Spilt` them based on the character count and send it separately.

```
 string strValue = "qwertyui oplkjhgfds azxcvb nm,. ;'[poerern asyqawqwdhkas,mdbn ahwdasda doiashdkjabdamd aiuasdghkjabdan dakshdkajdbkasdvsa askldhkajdahvd asdhkakjdad kahsdjbajkdbasd";
 int nLength = strValue.Length;

 if (nLength > 150)
 {
    //You can give the count in which you want to spilt the string
    var regex = new Regex(@".{100}");
    string result = regex.Replace(strValue, "$&" + Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show(result);
 }
```

Output result

[image: String spilt based on character count]